# CQ5 Manual Trigger of Thumbnail Creation workflow step

Tags: workflow, thumbnails, aem, dam

I've a set of thumbnail sizes initially configured in "/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html", as time past, I would like to add in additional set of sizes eg. 200x200, 300x300. 
How do I manually trigger the thumbnail creation workflow step without reuploading all the dam assets? 
Is it possible for an author to go to the "/damadmin", choose any image and click on workflow to manually trigger the thumbnail creation workflow step?

version: cq5.6.1

I'm still open to manual triggering of workflow. Another answer to this question thanks to dave, is to touch/update the original rendition's jcr:lastModified "/content/dam/./jcr:content/renditions/original/jcr:content"

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Was faced with a similar problem when creating new rendition sizes. One solution is to create an admin page (via a custom component/template) where given a particular path, will update the *Last modified* date of the assets under that tree.

This will then trigger the Update Asset workflow without the need for creating an additional workflow.

Comment: thanks for your reply, is it possible for an author to go to the "/damadmin", choose the any image and click on workflow to manually trigger the thumbnail creation workflow step?

Comment: Not that I've seen without creating a custom workflow, though it's an option we didn't look into in depth as it won't scale well regardless. If you have 100s of images in the DAM when you add a new rendition size, manually updating each one is a large burden on the editor.

Comment: if i were to implement what is mentioned in your answer, all i need to do is to "touch"/update the /content/dam/<asset_name>.<ext>/jcr:content/jcr:lastModified?

Comment: Yes exactly, updating the `jcr:lastModified` to current time will trigger the workflow for that asset.

Comment: i tried to update the asset's jcr:lastModified date and verified that the date is being updated correctly, however, the workflow doesn't seem to be triggered. This is the code snippet on how I update the jcr:lastModified "Session sess = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
    String asset = "/content/dam/mac/BG_stories.jpg/jcr:content";
    
    try {
        Node n = sess.getNode(asset);
        n.setProperty("jcr:lastModified", Calendar.getInstance());
        sess.save();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }"

Comment: voted your answer just need to touch the original rendition's jcr:lastModified: "/content/dam/<img_name>.<ext>/jcr:content/renditions/original/jcr:content"

Answer (score 1):

Manually Trigger Workflow

Options
1. Update asset lastModified

2. Click "Start" from Workflows console

```js
http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html
```

and provide Asset+"/jcr:content/renditions/original" as Payload

3. Curl:

```js
curl -u admin:admin 'http://localhost:4502/etc/workflow/instances' -F  "model=/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset/jcr:content/model" -F "_charset_=utf-8" -F ":status=browser" -F "payload=/content/dam/geometrixx-media/articles/andrew-novokov.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/original" -F "workflowTitle=" -F "startComment=" -F "payloadType=JCR_PATH"
```

4. Write Java Service spaghetti to do this
5. Write Javascript spaghetti to do this
6. Update DAM Asset UI as per

```js
http://experience-aem.blogspot.hk/2014/09/aem-6-classic-ui-starting-workflow-from-asset-editor.html
```

7. Add a menu item to context menu in DAM Asset tree to allow bulk trigger
8. Create a new similar to Tree Activate that just triggers the workflow